# Does CDN support video caching?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I am new Windows Azure and I uploaded all my images into CDN.

It provides In-Memory Cache that can store my application's data in memory to improve application responsiveness, performance and scale.

And also I upload my preview video content into Azure CDN but my application player doesn't play this video url which likes  http://cdn.mydomain.com/myapp/videos/preview/1460_preview.mp4

Do you know any idea ? How can I serve this content via Azure CDN.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure CDN is a 'pull' model & not a push model.  You don't upload into the CDN, you would upload into Blob storage or onto a VM's storage in the /CDN virtual directory.  On the initial request the CDN would grab the file from origin and populate the edge node.  The second request would be served from the CDN.

The CDN does support video files & a variety of streaming codes.

Overview of CDN:
 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-overview/

Best practices:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/03/18/best-practices-for-the-windows-azure-content-delivery-network.aspx

Another way to do this is to leverage the Azure Media Services:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/Media-Services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/#enable-cdn

Pat